# How does a "proxy" allow me to bypass company restrictions on internet traffic?

Tags: networking, proxy, eclipse

My company provides its employees with an "http proxy" (a domain name and port number) which we can specify in applications (like Eclipse, etc.) if the application needs to access something that it normally can't when we are connected to the company network normally.

I'm confused as to how this works. Is this proxy an alternative server that allows us to bypass the company firewall when accessing and downloading things from the internet? Does this proxy sit inside the company intranet?

Here's how I've organized things in my head...
[image]

Is this correct?

Comment: There simply is no way for us to guess about the internal setup of your network at work.  It certainly could be like above.  But also keep in mind that there are protocols for automatically configuring a proxy (WPAD) in most browsers, but some software doesn't use those automatic methods.  For that software you must specify the proxy manually.  **So maybe your network requires a proxy for all outbound access**, but most of the systems are automatically configured, in that setup the proxy could be the firewall, or behind the firewall.

Comment: It seems that instead of improving the rules of the standard proxy they added a second one and told you to use the latter to bypass the former.  It does not make much sense to me. Why force you use a proxy for acceptable accesses?